# Does Kubernetes support creating a persistence volume for a SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, kubernetes, minikube, persistent-volumes

Because I have tried creating persistence volume but not getting any value in there as I am creating volume in my minikube vm hosted in virtualbox.

yaml file for my deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1    
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: python-flask-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: python-flask-app-dep
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: python-flask-app-dep
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: mypod-pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mypvc
      containers:
        - name: python-app-container
          image: jackazjimmy/flask-test-demo-eks:v1
          volumeMounts:
           - mountPath: /app/instance/
             name: mypod-pvc
          ports:
            - containerPort: 31816  # Exposed port in your Dockerfile
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
            requests:
              cpu: 200m
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: python-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: python-flask-app-dep
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080  # External port
      targetPort: 31816  # Container port
  type: NodePort
```

Pvc yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mypvc
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
     storage: 10Gi
```

Pv yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mypv
spec:
storageClassName: ""
capacity:
   storage: 10Gi
accessModes:
   - ReadWriteOnce
hostPath:
   path: "/home/mydata"
```

After applying or creating all the required resources, whenever I connect through minikube ssh not able to get the files stores in local volume.
Any suggestion would be helpful:)

Comment: Run command kubectl get sc to check what is your default storage class.

Answer (score 1):

K8s almost support PV and PVC for all the apps runnable on K8s. As per your files, you left the storage class empty. It took the default storage class. There are high chance you don't have any storage class, or it might not be 10GB. Firstly you create a storage class where you want to store the volumes. It might be local or NFS outside of the cluster or using 3rd party solution like Minio or Rook. You also define this storage class's size (e.g., 10GB 100GB). Then you create a PV with this storage class with a unique name related to the app where you want to use it. Finally, you mount the PVC(Persistent Volume claim) with PV. Now your application will store data into PVC which is mounted with PV and that PV stores data into storage class.
This is an example of a storage class yaml file.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks @tauqeerahmad24 , but as we know, minikube does have a standard sc by default and i do have same sc in my minikube cluster with the specified description , still not able to get

Comment: Can you update your Question after running kubectl get sc and also with kubectl describe sc  mystorageclass  ? It will help us to understand where is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should not expect to be able to directly access the files in a Kubernetes volume.  Your question hints that perhaps you might be expecting to see the SQLite file on your host system; the volume storage is normally managed by Kubernetes itself, and it's usually not in a place where cluster administrators can access it (a typical example in a cloud environment would be an AWS EBS volume, attached to an EC2 instance, where there is not direct login access).

You also should not normally create PersistentVolume objects.  An in-cluster process called the *storage provisioner* sees a PersistentVolumeClaim, allocates some storage from somewhere, and creates the PersistentVolume.  [Minikube includes its own storage provisioner](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/#dynamic-provisioning-and-csi) and you should rely on that.

In the example you show, I suspect it will work if you delete all of these objects; delete the PersistentVolume object from your local repository, and delete the `storageClassName:` setting; and then redeploy.  If you `kubectl get pv` after doing this you should see that Minikube has created a PersistentVolume for you, backed by storage inside its VM.

---

More broadly I'd suggest that a Deployment attached to a ReadWriteOnce PersistentVolumeClaim isn't a great pattern.  You can never create a second replica because it won't be able to mount the volume, and this can cause trouble in even routine update scenarios.  A [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) is a little more complex to set up, but it means that each replica will get its own automatically-created PersistentVolumeClaim.

The other corresponding large-scale comment is that SQLite might not be the right database choice for something running in Kubernetes.  SQLite intrinsically depends on the database being in a filesystem-accessible file, but it's hard to get a filesystem that can be accessed from multiple nodes (ReadWriteMany access mode).  A more typical setup would be to deploy a relational database like PostgreSQL or MySQL in its own separate StatefulSet, and then you can have Deployments that attach to that database, without mounting any storage at all, and therefore with as many `replicas:` as you need (and as the database can support).